# Cows in the FooLand city

Tags: java, fibonacci

I was going through this problem-

> Cows in the FooLand city are interesting animals. One of their
>   specialties is related to producing offsprings. A cow in FooLand
>   produces its first calve (female calf) at the age of two years and
>   proceeds to produce other calves (one female calf a year).
>
> Now the farmer Harold wants to know how many animals would he have at
>   the end of N years, if we assume that none of the calves die, given
>   that initially, he has only one female calf?
>
> Input:
>
> The first line contains a single integer T denoting the number of test
>   cases. Each line of the test case contains a single integer N as
>   described in the problem.
>
> Output:
>
> For each test case print in new line the number of animals expected at
>   the end of N years

I solved this by below code-

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner ab=new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=ab.nextInt();  //number of test cases

    for (int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        int n=ab.nextInt(); //years
        int arr[]=new int[n];
        arr[0]=1;
        arr[1]=2;
        if(n>2)
        {
            for(i=2;i<n;i++)
            {
                arr[i]=arr[i-1]+arr[i-2];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(arr[arr.length-1]);


     }
}
```

But when i searched on net they have given a much complex solution at net-

https://hackerranksolutionc.blogspot.in/2017/10/cows-of-fooland.html

I tried matching the output and found the result is same for small numbers but is different for very large number.

I want to know that is there anything wrong in my solution?

Comment: Step through both programs with a debugger, work out the value at which the result diverges.

Comment: @AndyTurner The algorithm completely different for both programs..I want to know is my way correct?

Comment: and yet they purport to solve the same problem. You should work out how the two solutions relate. For example, you could look at the answers for N=0, N=1, N=2 etc. Note that this doesn't tell you if either is *correct*; for that, you'd actually have to think about whether the result is what you expect mathematically.

Comment: The correct answer is probably 1 since it is unusual that only female cows would reproduce ...

Comment: For what input the program return wrong value (not as expected) ?

Comment: @cOder for input value 100 output for both programs different but for 4,5,6,7,8,15,30 output of both programs same

Comment: @Henry yOU mean for all inputs output should be 1

Comment: How come that in your algo one test case depends on previous ones ? Why keep long array of values when you only need the sum  ? Also you are requested to have one argument (number of years) but you have two (number of cases) . To debug you need to input a value that yields wrong output and step through the code using debugger.

Comment: @c0der "One test case depends on previous one.."no..it doesn't...t is number of test cases and i started a for loop and for each test case i run the algorithm.." you are requested to have one argument "..no..as per ques we have to input number of test case and then each value of test case.

Comment: My guess is that for "very large numbers" you get an integer overflow somewhere in between. But how would we know without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @lexicore I tried changing int  to long..but still output not matches for large numbers...i am checking using [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)

Comment: In most of the questions, N is of the order 10^18, so the fibonacci for such large number becomes overflowed in C++ like languages. So they ask you to compute the answer modulo 10^9+7. You did not do so, and probably the solutions online did it, that's why for answers larger that 10e9+7, it's showing different output.

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution won't work if the expected time complexity is `O(log N).`
You can convert the recursive equation in the form of matrix and solve it using matrix exponentiation.

For a more generalized version solve this problem https://www.spoj.com/problems/SEQ/